# Закрытие формы с таймером ломает программу

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер

Есть форма с работающим в ней таймером, где за каждый тик выполняются действия

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
//всякие действия
Fuu();
//всякие действия
```

и функция Fuu(), которая вызывается выше

```
private void Fuu()
{
            buf = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            g = this.CreateGraphics();   //вот тут и ломается
            g = Graphics.FromImage(buf);
 
            //далее идут другие действия в функции с pictureBox1, битмапом и графикой
 
            if (end)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                this.Close();
            }
}
```

и в этой функции есть проверка на то, завершать ли работу с этой формой. Как только она проходит, форма закрывается, но как-то продолжает залезать в функцию таймера, а следовательно и в Fuu(), который в свою очередь всё ломает в указанной выше строке.
Пытался изначально сделать закрытие формы в самом таймере, результат тот же.
Вопрос: как починить?

Comment: В событии `FormClosing` сделайте `timer.Dispose()`

Comment: Не помогло. По итогу я просто эту проверку на закрытие просто добавил еще перед вызовом функции.

Comment: `всё ломает` _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: В .NET как минимум 3 разных таймера, имеющих разное поведение и назначение. `Stop()` и `Enabled = false` - одно и тоже, это указывает на то, что вы не понимаете, что делаете, постарайтесь добиться понимания происходящего. Текст ошибки вы оставили в секрете, по неизвесным никому причинам. Спрятали часть кода, от которой тоже может что-то зависеть или точно не зависит? Почему вы так уверены? Интервал вызова таймера - тоже в секрете. Время работы `Tick` - тоже неизвестно, оно дольше работает, чем интервал, или точно не дольше? Хотя зависит от типа таймера. И самый главный вопрос: а зачем таймер?